# Xamarin ios archive crash after signed

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a iOS project, which link a binding library and correctly works without issues.
But when I send xarchive to my customer (so xarchive is signed from him), his app crashes at launch
It seem I miss something during the xarchive build?
Using an external library maybe I have to check additional options in xamarin studio build tab?

**UPDATE:**
pluggin iPad and launching Xcode devices windows, error is:

> Runtime error: The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be
>   loaded

Searching I found this:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/questions/error-mscorlib-not-found/

> This issue occurs when the hidden .monotouch-32 and .monotouch-64
>   folders are missing from the .xcarchive for signing / IPA creation,
>   triggering the runtime error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Ok i did as you suggested. Can you remove (if yours) negative valuation and (i hope so) make a positive valuation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm issue was related to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/questions/error-mscorlib-not-found/

My archive was uploaded to my owncloud company. Owncloud client doesn't upload hidden files/folders (as **.monotouch-32** and **.monotouch-64**), so xarchive received by customer was different and smaller and did not contain all references.
I hope this help other people will have this issue.